# save db access file in to pendrive

Tags: performance, ms-access, usb-drive

I have a very small application. This save data in mdb file (this mdb file only have 2 tables). MDB file is stored in my PC. From application I can set the path to my .mdb file.

I have installed my app in 2 PC (office and home) and now I want to save mdb file in 1 pendrive.

This way when I go home only I will have to plug the pendrive and already I will have the data. Ditto for when I go to the office. In the 2 PC only I will set the path to the pendrive.

My question is:

is there any incoveniente in this method? Possibility of error, low performance....?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: I would never do anything but read-only access of an MDB/ACCDB stored on a Flash thumb drive. It's just too dangerous, i.e., too easy to accidentally bump the thing and have it disconnect.

Comment: yes finally I will save access to hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

If the application is small and we are talking about modern hardware (USB 2.0) then it should be feasible.

You'd have to take care of what happens if you extract the drive unexpectedly, this is, leave no state in memory, save everything as it is done.

Answer (score 1):

The IO performance might be slightly lower than that of a conventional hard drive. This will be dependant on the size of the db, number of rows, etc.

Also, you have to take into account backups. Pendrive corrupts, lost/stolen?

Also, how sure are you that the pendrive will always be mapped to the same drive letter?